# Why the DBT macro executes before the pre_hook statement in an incremental model?

Tags: dbt

Does anyone know why the pre_hook statement gets executed after the macro `append_placekeys` is called?

I am creating a Temporary table in the pre_hook configuration which is going to be called by the macro. However, DBT logs showed the macro executing before the creation of the temp table.

```
{{
    config(
           materialized='incremental',
           unique_key='DX_ID',
           pre_hook=[
                """
                    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE DXH_STORE_PLCK_IN
                    AS
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        s.dx_id AS msa_id,
                        s.nm AS store_name,
                        s.city AS city,
                        s.state AS state,
                        s.address AS street_addr,
                        s.zip5 AS zipcode,
                        s.country AS COUNTRY_CODE,
                        s.latitude AS LATITUDE,
                        s.longitude AS LONGITUDE,
                        COALESCE(p.last_updt_dt, TO_DATE('2023-01-01')) AS last_updt_dt
                    FROM {{ ref('dx_store_attr') }} s
                {%- if is_incremental() %}
                        FULL JOIN {{ this }} p USING (dx_id)
                    WHERE
                        (
                            p.placekey IS NULL
                        OR
                            DATEDIFF(day, p.last_updt_dt::DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::DATE) > 90
                        )
                    ORDER BY last_updt_dt ASC, s.dx_id ASC
                    LIMIT 3000
                {%- else %}
                    LIMIT 50000
                {%- endif -%}
                ;
                """
            ],
        tags=["dx", "refresh:daily"]
    )
}}
--load dx_store_plck
{{
    append_placekeys(
        tbl_in='DXH_STORE_PLCK_IN',
        tbl_out='DXH_STORE_PLCK_TEMP'
 )
}}
SELECT
 t.msa_id AS dx_id,
 t.placekey AS placekey,
 t.error AS error,
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS last_updt_dt
FROM
 {{ database }}.{{ schema }}.DXH_STORE_PLCK_TEMP AS t
```

DBT Logs:

```bash
[0m20:44:55.939031 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: SQL status: SUCCESS 1 in 0.19 seconds
[0m20:44:55.940927 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: Using snowflake connection "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"
[0m20:44:55.942096 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: On model.XXX.dx_store_plck: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.3.0", "profile_name": "XXX", "target_name": "dev", "node_id": "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"} */
CALL DB.SCHEMA_DEV.APPEND_PLACEKEYS(
          'DXH_STORE_PLCK_IN',
          (
            SELECT object_construct(MAPPING.*)
            FROM (
              SELECT
                'msa_id' AS PRIMARY_KEY,
                'store_name' AS LOCATION_NAME,
                'city' AS CITY,
                'state' AS REGION,
                'street_addr' AS STREET_ADDRESS,
                'zipcode' AS POSTAL_CODE,
                'LATITUDE' AS LATITUDE,
                'LONGITUDE' AS LONGITUDE,
                'false' AS strict_address_match,
                'false' AS strict_name_match
            ) AS MAPPING
          ),
          'DXH_STORE_PLCK_TEMP', 'temp', 'get_placekeys_v', 1000
        );
[0m20:44:56.882161 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: SQL status: SUCCESS 1 in 0.94 seconds
[0m20:44:56.888032 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: Writing injected SQL for node "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"
[0m20:44:56.891930 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: finished collecting timing info
[0m20:44:56.893285 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: Began executing node model.XXX.dx_store_plck
[0m20:44:56.897175 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: Using snowflake connection "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"
[0m20:44:56.898207 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: On model.sdna_us_project.dx_store_plck: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.3.0", "profile_name": "XXX", "target_name": "dev", "node_id": "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"} */
select current_warehouse() as warehouse
[0m20:44:57.061101 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: SQL status: SUCCESS 1 in 0.16 seconds
[0m20:44:57.063617 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: Using snowflake connection "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"
[0m20:44:57.064833 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: On model.XXX.dx_store_plck: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.3.0", "profile_name": "XXX", "target_name": "dev", "node_id": "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"} */
use warehouse   XXX_M;
[0m20:44:57.326229 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: SQL status: SUCCESS 1 in 0.26 seconds
[0m20:44:57.356896 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: Using snowflake connection "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"
[0m20:44:57.358488 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: On model.XXX.dx_store_plck: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.3.0", "profile_name": "sdna_us", "target_name": "dev", "node_id": "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"} */
USE ROLE FUNCTIONAL_ROLE_XXX;
[0m20:44:57.508780 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: SQL status: SUCCESS 1 in 0.15 seconds
[0m20:44:57.510018 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: Using snowflake connection "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"
[0m20:44:57.510897 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: On model.XXX.dx_store_plck: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.3.0", "profile_name": "sdna_us", "target_name": "dev", "node_id": "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"} */
alter session set query_tag ='DB.SCHEMA_DEV.DX_STORE_PLCK';
[0m20:44:57.648295 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: SQL status: SUCCESS 1 in 0.14 seconds
[0m20:44:57.652786 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: Using snowflake connection "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"
[0m20:44:57.653900 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: On model.sdna_us_project.dx_store_plck: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.3.0", "profile_name": "XXX", "target_name": "dev", "node_id": "model.XXX.dx_store_plck"} */
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE DXH_STORE_PLCK_IN
                    AS
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        s.dx_id AS msa_id,
                        s.nm AS store_name,
                        s.city AS city,
                        s.state AS state,
                        s.address AS street_addr,
                        s.zip5 AS zipcode,
                        s.country AS COUNTRY_CODE,
                        s.latitude AS LATITUDE,
                        s.longitude AS LONGITUDE,
                        COALESCE(p.last_updt_dt, TO_DATE('2023-01-01')) AS last_updt_dt
                    FROM DB.SCHEMA_DEV.store_attr s
                        FULL JOIN DB.SCHEMA_DEV.dx_store_plck p USING (dx_id)
                    WHERE
                        (
                            p.placekey IS NULL
                        OR
                            DATEDIFF(day, p.last_updt_dt::DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::DATE) > 90
                        )
                    ORDER BY last_updt_dt ASC, s.dx_id ASC
                    LIMIT 3000;
[0m20:44:59.140263 [debug] [Thread-1  ]: SQL status: SUCCESS 1 in 1.49 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

dbt takes two passes over your model file; first to parse it and build the dag, and then to actually execute it.

In order to properly template (parse) your model, it has to execute any macros contained in it. (Among other reasons, `ref` is also a macro, and is critical for this step). This means that your `append_placekeys` macro gets executed twice; first, when the model is parsed, and then, when it is executed.

You can prevent this by using the special jinja variable called `execute`. `execute` is False during the first parsing pass, but True during the actual model execution. I would probably edit the macro itself to add an `{% if execute %}` block around the database call, but you could also just gate the whole macro call in the model file:

```sql
{{
    config(
           ...
    )
}}
--load dx_store_plck
{% if execute %}
{{
    append_placekeys(
        tbl_in='DXH_STORE_PLCK_IN',
        tbl_out='DXH_STORE_PLCK_TEMP'
 )
}}
{% endif %}
SELECT
 t.msa_id AS dx_id,
 t.placekey AS placekey,
 t.error AS error,
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS last_updt_dt
FROM
 {{ database }}.{{ schema }}.DXH_STORE_PLCK_TEMP AS t
```

All that aside, this code contains a bunch of dbt antipatterns. You should really never have to write any DDL when using dbt. Both your pre-hook and the macro are relatively fragile operations, and you should re-write your model logic so you don't need them. Finally, models should pretty much always select `from {{ ref('a_model') }}` or `from {{ source('a_source', 'a_source_tbl') }}`, and not directly from a database relation, as you're doing here.

Comment: Hi @tconbeer. Thanks for your quick reply. I tried to answer las friday but stackoverflow entered in read-only mode due to maintenance.

I know about the dbt antipaterns I am using in this model. However I couldn't find any dbt pattern which allow me to do something similar. 
In my opinion the main issue is the cycle created between temp table DXH_STORE_PLCK_IN and the incremental model.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the **{% if execute %}** in the model definition but it did not change the order. Still the **append_placekeys** macro is executing before the **pre_hook** statements. By the way, inside the macro there was already an if execute statement.

Comment: That's very strange. I don't see how that's possible -- [this](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/blob/4b7ee7372d87efc2b9c6929203fcfb41930b0b3e/dbt/include/snowflake/macros/materializations/incremental.sql#L40) is the code for the incremental materialization. Hooks are called before any of the other code is executed. Does this happen with both incremental and full refresh runs?

Comment: I also tried calling the macro inside the **pre_hook** after the table craetion. Now the order is as expected (table creation first, macro later) but the table passed into the macro seems to be empty. I tried also as a regular table instead of a TEMP table. Same result, table is empty when the macro is called.    ????

Comment: I haven't try a full_refresh. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

This was the resulting final model:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='DX_ID',
        pre_hook=[
                """
                    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {{ database }}.{{ schema }}.dxh_store_plck_in
                    AS
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        s.dx_id AS msa_id,
                        s.btg_store_nm AS store_name,
                        s.btg_city AS city,
                        s.btg_state AS state,
                        s.btg_address AS street_addr,
                        s.btg_zip5 AS zipcode,
                        'US' AS COUNTRY_CODE,
                        s.latitude AS LATITUDE,
                        s.longitude AS LONGITUDE,
                        COALESCE(p.last_updt_dt, TO_DATE('2023-01-01')) AS last_updt_dt
                    FROM {{ ref('dx_store_attr') }} s
                        FULL JOIN {{ this }} p USING (dx_id)
                {%- if is_incremental() %}
                    WHERE
                        (
                            p.placekey IS NULL
                        OR
                            DATEDIFF(day, p.last_updt_dt::DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::DATE) > 90
                        )
                    ORDER BY last_updt_dt ASC, s.dx_id ASC
                    LIMIT 5000
                {%- endif -%}
                ;
                """,
                """
                {{
                    append_placekeys(
                        tbl_in=database|as_text ~'.' ~ schema|as_text ~'.dxh_store_plck_in',
                        tbl_out=database|as_text ~'.' ~ schema|as_text ~'.dxh_store_plck_temp'
                    )
                }}
                """
            ],
        tags=["dx", "refresh:daily"]
    )
}}

--load dx_store_plck

SELECT
    t.msa_id AS dx_id,
    t.placekey AS placekey,
    t.error AS error,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS last_updt_dt
FROM {{ database }}.{{ schema }}.dxh_store_plck_temp AS t
```

Comment: As @tconbeer mentioned previously, this solution even though working, have several problems. 
1. There is a Cycle between **dxh_store_plck_in** and **{{this}}** model (dx_store_plck), which is a dbt antipattern
2. Manually creating a model (**dxh_store_plck_in**) is a clear dbt antipattern
3. Manually setting **{{database}}** and **{{schema}}** to fully reference a model instead of using **ref** or **source** is another dbt antipattern.

Now is working, but if anyone want to suggest a better approach or a good design pattern for this problem, please feel free to chime in.